# Factoring numbers

Tags: javascript, loops

Trying to factor a number i.e. 7! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 5040

Started off with this but I haven't been able to wrap my head on how to loop this:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  for (i = 1; i < num; i ++) {
   var math = i * i;
    math++;

  return math;

}
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It appears you forgot to ask a specific answerable question.

Comment: that's a factorial you want, not a factor

Answer (score 1):

you have several mistakes in that code ,, first you multiply **i*i** ,, and you increase **math** with one ,, and you return inside the for loop so you will execute only 1 iteration ,,

there are several ways to implement it ,,
I'll write down 2 of them

```
function get_factorial(num){
   if(num < 0){
      throw new RangeError('Factorial is only defined for non-negative integers');
   }
   var res = 1;
   for(var i = num;num >1 ; num--){
       res *= num;
   }
   return res;
}
```

and recursive way :

```
function get_factorial(num){
    if(num < 0){
      throw new RangeError('Factorial is only defined for non-negative integers');
    }
    if(num ==1 || num ==0){
      return 1;
    }
    return num * get_factorial(num-1);
}
```

** now throwing exception in case of negative numbers instead of returning strings ,, based on Paul suggestion

Comment: You should consider `throw new RangeError('Factorial is only defined for non-negative integers');` instead of `return`ing a _String_

Comment: I think this is much better ,, I'll edit the code now :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the third line you have there.
You are making a math mistake there, and you are also making a mistake with the following lines - think carefully about what you want to loop on, i.e. the step that you want to do multiple times.

I hope that helps, I'm afraid we aren't big on doling out solutions and this is a reasonably simple task. If you are still having trouble revisit some of the basics of programming including for loops and try writing out a diagram of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = 1;
for(int i =1; i <= num; i++){
  total *= i;
}
return total;
```